# Spring Boot, CXF Spring MVC. Not exposing web service on JBoss

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cxf, jboss6.x

I've been googling for the last 2 days and still can't figure out why it wont expose the SOAP web service. It works when I run it locally using Tomcat and Spring Boot. In the jboss-deployment-structure, jpa, javaee-api and webservices has been excluded. Also, there are no exceptions in sysout or logs. Only the message specified further down (HTTP 405). Even checked through TRACE logs.

JBoss Version: 6.4.4 (or 6.4.0)
Spring Boot: 1.3.0
CXF: 3.0.4
Spring MVC: From Spring Boot parent

I get this message:

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported.

When debugging, I placed a breakpoint in class: DispatcherServlet, which then in getHandlerAdapter returned HttpRequestHandlerAdapter. Further along, it calls the HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle which again calls handleRequest on a WebContentGenerator. This only supports GET or HEAD requests.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {
                ApplicationConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {
                "/*"
        };
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ApplicationServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({
        RepositoryConfig.class,
        WebConfig.class,
        WsProviderConfig.class
})
public class ApplicationConfig {
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public SelftestController selftestController() {
        return new SelftestController();
    }
}


@Configuration
public class WsProviderConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WsProviderConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/soap/*");
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    Bus bus() {
        SpringBus bus = new SpringBus();
        bus.getFeatures().addAll(Arrays.asList(new WSAddressingFeature(), new LoggingFeature()));
        return bus;
    }

    @Bean
    PlayerServiceV1 defaultPlayerService() {
        return new DefaultPlayerService();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void publishWebServices() {
        LOGGER.info("Publishing WebServices");
        DefaultPlayerService defaultPlayerService = context.getBean(DefaultPlayerService.class);
        Bus bus = context.getBean(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID, Bus.class);
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, defaultPlayerService);
        endpoint.publish("/test/players");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The webservice interface has been generated using JAXB-RI. But as I said, this works fine locally, so seems like I'm missing a HandlerAdapter or something? Tried to remove the selftest configuration by commenting out WebConfig.java, so that it was not exposed since I thought it might be because of some problem where I had two ServletDispatcher. But it didnt help.